# how to record voice and play in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have implemented voice recording functionality in our project but i couldn't have control on stop and discard buttons. In second time not able to record the voice after clicking the discard button.
After clicking discard also the audio file is playing and not able to click start button again.

Please help on this one

Here is the source code

```
.h file

@interface VoiceInput : UIViewController
                                 <AVAudioRecorderDelegate>
{
//Audio record

  float remainingDelayTime;
  float remainingRecordTime;
  UILabel *delayLabel;

  UIProgressView *progressView;
  AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
  NSTimer *delayTimer;
  NSTimer *recordTimer;
  BOOL toggle;
  NSURL *recordedTmpFile;
  NSError *error;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *delayTimer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *recordTimer;
@end

.m file

@implementation VoiceInput
@synthesize progressView;
@synthesize recorder;
@synthesize delayTimer;
@synthesize recordTimer;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    toggle = YES;
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&error];
}

-(void)startPushed
{
   if (toggle)
    {
        remainingDelayTime = 4.0;
        delayTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(delayTimerFired:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
        toggle = NO;
        NSMutableDictionary *rs = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [rs setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
        [rs setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
        [rs setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
        recordedTmpFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f.%@", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] * 1000.0, @"caf"]]];
        NSLog(@"USING FILE CALLED: %@", recordedTmpFile);

        recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedTmpFile settings:rs error:&error];
        [recorder setDelegate:self];
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        [recorder record];

    }
    else
    {
        toggle = YES;
        NSLog(@"Using File Called: %@", recordedTmpFile);
        [recorder stop];
    }


  self.discardButton.enabled = NO;
  self.startButton.enabled = NO;
  self.stopButton.enabled = YES;

}

-(void)stopPushed
{
if([self.recorder isRecording])
  {
    [self.recorder stop];

    if(remainingRecordTime >= 1.0)
    {
      [self.recordTimer invalidate];
    }
}
self.delayLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
 self.delayLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Record in ..."];

  self.discardButton.enabled = YES;
  self.playbackButton.enabled = YES;
  self.startButton.enabled = NO;
  self.stopButton.enabled = NO;

}

-(void)playbackPushed
{ 
  AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recordedTmpFile    error:&error];
    [avPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [avPlayer play];

  self.discardButton.enabled = YES;
  self.playbackButton.enabled = YES;
  self.returnButton.enabled = YES;
  self.startButton.enabled = YES;
  self.stopButton.enabled = YES;

}

-(void)discardPushed
{
  [self.recorder deleteRecording];
  self.progressView.progress = 0;
  self.delayLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
  self.delayLabel.text = @"Record in ...";

  self.discardButton.enabled = NO;
  self.playbackButton.enabled = NO;
  self.startButton.enabled = YES;
  self.stopButton.enabled = YES;

}

-(void)delayTimerFired:(NSTimer *)theDelayTimer
{
  self.progressView.progress = 0;
  remainingDelayTime -= 1.0;
  NSLog(@"fired %f", remainingDelayTime);
  self.delayLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  self.delayLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Record in %2.0f",
                            remainingDelayTime];

  if(remainingDelayTime <= 0.0)
  {
    [self.delayTimer invalidate];
    self.delayLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Recording"];

    [self.recorder recordForDuration:TIME];
    remainingRecordTime = TIME;
    recordTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:TIME_DECREMENT
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(recordTimerFired:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
  }

}

-(void)recordTimerFired:(NSTimer *)theRecordTimer
{
  remainingRecordTime -= TIME_DECREMENT;
  NSLog(@"fired %f", remainingRecordTime);
  self.progressView.progress = (TIME - remainingRecordTime)/TIME;

  if(remainingRecordTime <= 0.0)
  {
    [self.recordTimer invalidate];
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on this.You can Start recording by this :-

```
- (void) startRecording
{
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
    [audioSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:&err];

    if(err)
    {
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }

    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
    err = nil;

    if(err)
    {
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }

    recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // We can use kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 (4:1 compression) or kAudioFormatLinearPCM for nocompression
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];

    // We can use 44100, 32000, 24000, 16000 or 12000 depending on sound quality
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];

    // We can use 2(if using additional h/w) or 1 (iPhone only has one microphone)
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    [recordSetting setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12800] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
    [recordSetting setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSetting setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax] forKey: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];  

    NSString *str;
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MySound.caf",DOCUMENTS_FOLDER];


    NSLog(@"recorderFilePath: %@",str);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:str];

    err = nil;
    recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];
    if(!recorder)
    {
        NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        UIAlertView *alert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: [err localizedDescription]
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        return;
    }

    //prepare to record
    [recorder setDelegate:self];
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

    BOOL audioHWAvailable = audioSession.inputIsAvailable;
    if (! audioHWAvailable) {
        UIAlertView *cantRecordAlert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: @"Audio input hardware not available"
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [cantRecordAlert show];

        return;
    }

    // start recording
    [recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) 20];
    }
```

This will start your recording.After it you can stop recording :-

```
- (void) stopRecording
{
[recorder stop];
}
```

Now you can play your recording by this :-

```
- (void)playRecordingSound
{
if(!recorderFilePath)
    recorderFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MySound.caf", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER] ;
    if(soundID)
{
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
}

//Get a URL for the sound file
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath isDirectory:NO];

//Use audio sevices to create the sound
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);

//Use audio services to play the sound
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

}

Hope it helps Thanks :)